# How can I only have sound when being called (phone)?

Tags: audio, calls

In my Android phone, I have the following options for sound:

- Media volume
- Alarm volume
- Ring volume

However, if I increase ring volume, I also get each time a sound when I get a Whatsapp message, Facebook massage etc.

Is it possible to (temporarily) get sound only when I will be (phone) called (by another person)?

(background: I always leave my sound off, but I expect an important phone call today I do not want to miss).

Mobile: Motorola S5+, Android 8.1.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats app calls or phone calls?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio phone calls (when I am called by someone else)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Go to **System settings**->**Notifications**->Select WhatsApp->Choose **Block all** and/or **Show silently** according to your need.

Do the same for Facebook.

Comment: Thanks; I was hoping for a better solution, because whatsapp/FB were just examples, I have lots of apps making sounds for notifications (mail, text messages, linkedin, ...) if I switch on sounds. But these will rule out the most important, thanks.